# Using Firebase OpenID Connect provider as Azure Function App Identity Provider

Tags: firebase, azure, firebase-authentication, azure-functions, openid-connect

I have a react-native app that handles authentication using Firebase. That works great

The app calls serverless functions in Azure which id like to add authentication to by selecting an identity provider.

[Azure Function App Identity Provider Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv1ei.png)

Ive tried using OpenID Connect with the following configuration values but had no luck

metadata url: [https://securetoken.google.com/{my-project-id}/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://securetoken.google.com/%7Bmy-project-id%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration)

client id: 412*********-3gp****************************.apps.googleusercontent.com

client secret: taken from the link below

[https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=1&project={my-project-id}&supportedpurview=project](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=1&project=%7Bmy-project-id%7D&supportedpurview=project)

[Firebase OpenId configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJotA.png)

**Process:**

1. Get idToken from the already-authenticated Firebase user in my app
2. Pass that (jwt)idToken as a Bearer authentication header when calling my Azure function

**Result:**

401 unauthorised response
No response body is present

**Expected result:**

200 response

Does anyone know if its possible to use Firebase as an OpenId identity provider and if so, where I should get the correct ClientId and Client secret values from?

I notice the are some value in the Firebase console and also some in the Google cloud console

Comment: can you let me know how to create identity provider in azure because i can only see google, facebook and azure as identity provider.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing exactly the same issue this morning and managed to get it working.

I initially did the same as you and set the client ID to be xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com. That client ID value came from the same page you have liked to above for the client secret. Those values still resulted in the 401 error.

When I changed the client ID to be the Firebase project ID it all started working as expected.